# Error in goto. (C#)

Tags: c#

I'm making a fake shell program, and I want to be able to trigger an error screen by inputting a certain line of code.

Here's the affected bit of my code:

```
                Console.Title = "Command Prompt";
                OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
                Version ver = os.Version;
                ver.ToString();
                if (os.VersionString.Equals("Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0"))
                        {
                                Console.WriteLine("Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]");
                                Console.WriteLine("(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. \n");
                                goto a;
                        }

                else
   ver_error:
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: OS '" + os.VersionString + "' Missing from libraries, \nnot yet implemented?\n");
                    Console.WriteLine("Available Operating Systems:\nWndows 8.1, Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0 ");
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress enter to boot Error Protocol, type exit to exit.\n");
                error_test:
                    string errorProtocol;
                    errorProtocol = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (errorProtocol.Equals("")) 
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Booting Error Protocol...");
                                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                                goto error_report;
                            }
                    else if (errorProtocol.Equals("exit"))
                            {
                                goto end;
                            }
                    else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Not a valid response.");
                                    goto error_test;
                            }
                }
    /* C:\Users\18LeunJA dir */
    a:
                Console.Write("C:\\Users\\18LeunJA>");
                string userValueFromStart;
                userValueFromStart = Console.ReadLine();
                if (userValueFromStart.Equals("exit"))
                        {
                                goto end;
                        }
                else if (userValueFromStart.Equals("triggerOSError"))
                {
                    goto ver_error;
                }
```

The affected code is the "ver_error:" line. Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

EDIT: I have attempted moving the ver_error inside the else body, but instead, it says the label has not been referenced, and that there is 'No such label 'ver_error' within the scope of the goto statement.

When outside, the error 'Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labelled statement' appears.

Comment: What is the error _exactly_?

Comment: Move the label to be the first line of the `else` body. But you just should never use `goto` at all normally

Comment: Strongly recomment not to use goto in C#..

Comment: Aside from anything else, this is a really hard-to-read coding style. Have you considered trying to *avoid* goto instead of just changing the code to make it work?

Comment: Surely the C# compiler is fatally confused by the brace indenting style.  I know I am.

Comment: What did methods ever do to you?! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be code:

Try to put the parentheses of `else` immediate after `else`

```
Console.Title = "Command Prompt";
OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
Version ver = os.Version;
ver.ToString();
if (os.VersionString.Equals("Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0"))
        {
                Console.WriteLine("Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]");
                Console.WriteLine("(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. \n");
                goto a;
        }

else
{
ver_error:
    Console.WriteLine("Error: OS '" + os.VersionString + "' Missing from libraries, \nnot yet implemented?\n");
    Console.WriteLine("Available Operating Systems:\nWndows 8.1, Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0 ");
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress enter to boot Error Protocol, type exit to exit.\n");
error_test:
    string errorProtocol;
    errorProtocol = Console.ReadLine();
    if (errorProtocol.Equals("")) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Booting Error Protocol...");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                goto error_report;
            }
    else if (errorProtocol.Equals("exit"))
            {
                goto end;
            }
    else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not a valid response.");
                    goto error_test;
            }
}
/* C:\Users\18LeunJA dir */
a:
    Console.Write("C:\\Users\\18LeunJA>");
    string userValueFromStart;
    userValueFromStart = Console.ReadLine();
    if (userValueFromStart.Equals("exit"))
            {
                    goto end;
            }
    else if (userValueFromStart.Equals("triggerOSError"))
    {
        goto ver_error;
    }
```

By the way `goto` will work in the same scope only. you are calling `goto` from `if` part to `else` part - which is wrong..

Comment: It needs some explanations to be anyhow helpful for the OP